# Use existing string locale in Trans Component

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have 3 strings that contain the same values as those below

```js
translation: {
   "companyName": "Stackoverflow",
   "welcome": "Welcome to <1>Stackoverflow</1>",
   "contact": "Contact to <1>Stackoverflow</1>
}
```

I am using `Trans` component for `welcome` and `contact`

```html
<Trans i18nKey="welcome">
    Welcome to <strong>Stackoverflow</strong>
</Trans>
<Trans i18nKey="welcome">
    Contact to <strong>Stackoverflow</strong>
</Trans>
```

Now I don't want to repeat `Stackoverflow` three times I want to use `companyName` in Trans component or any other way so that I don't have to repeat that again and again. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use props to pass this value to your translation strings:

**Sample code:**

```
const companyName = 'Stackoverflow';

<Trans i18nKey="welcome" companyName={companyName}>
  Welcome to <strong>{{companyName}}</strong>
</Trans>

<Trans i18nKey="contact" companyName={companyName}>
  Contact to <strong>{{companyName}}</strong>
</Trans>
```

**Resulting translation strings:**

```
Welcome to <strong>Stackoverflow</strong>

Contact to <strong>Stackoverflow</strong>
```